# Why doesn't Vera kill Elliot?

Tags: mr-robot

Earlier in S01E06, Elliot threatens Vera (a murderous psycho) with destroying his operation should any harm come to him or Shayla.

At the end of S01E06, Vera has just killed Shayla and his own brother.

He forces Elliot to look at his dead brother:

> Dead proof. My operation is over. So go on, crash it, burn it to the ground. Doesn't matter. I'm gone.

So why doesn't Vera (who is very prone to murdering any person who offends him in the slightest) also just kill Elliot (who recently put Vera in jail)?

(Later in S04 we learn that after the events in S01E06, Vera goes home to the Dominican Republic. So, in S01E06, it would seem that he had no intention of staying in the US anyway. Which would make killing Elliot that much more convenient.)